# Building first PC in 7 years, some confusion hooking up case I/O connectors

Tags: motherboard, fan, case

The case I have is the [Rosewell THOR V2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811147053).

The motherboard I have is the [ASUS Z87-PRO](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131979).

I have hooked up majority of the case connectors.

- power sw
- reset sw
- p+/-
- HD LED
- AAFP
- USB 2.0
- USB 3.0

Note: The Speaker, Ground, Ground, and +5V connectors are not plugged into the appropriate spot above the power/reset sw connectors because they are not present.

[image]

However, I am now left with some connectors I don't know what to do with.

There are:

- 2 power connectors
- SATA connector
- FAN A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, B3

[image]

I am primarily concerned what to do with the 6 FAN connectors.

[image]

The case comes with 4 fans.  All 4 of these fans have a power connector dangling from them, and I've already plugged those fan connectors into the motherboard.

[image]

Could someone offer me some assistance here?  It has been some time!  What do I do with the fan connectors?  Also, what are the Speaker, ground, ground, +5V connectors?  They are not bundled with the rest of the case connectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install a Fan, you plug the Fan into those connectors. By doing so you can manually adjust the speed of the fans probably by some switch on your case.
There's Fan connectors on the motherboard aswell, which let's you control the speed of the fans with a program (provided to you by your motherboard manufacturer)

Comment: I thought about this.  So then would it be accurate to say the power connectors are what powers the switches on the front of the case to control the fan speeds?

Comment: Yes, that would be accurate. You could ofcourse simply test this by connecting a fan to a connector and flip the switch on your case and see/hear if it spins up.    Personally I prefer having them connected to my motherboard, cuz the program provided to you by your motherboard manufacturer can adjust the fan-speeds according to the temperatures within your case (but this ofcourse is a personal preference)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your responses!  I think I will begin by connecting the fans to the case connectors because the cable management looks great :)  If my temperatures are a problem for me, I will connect them directly to the motherboard.  Thanks again!